# How call a dataframe using paste in a Loop

Tags: r

I have 4 dataframes (df_1,df_2,df_3,df_4), each one belongs to a group. I Would like create a column with group name (group name are rows in dataframe fruit, as shown below)in each dataframe from a loop, because I have a situation with more databases and it would be laborious without to use a loop

```
columna<-c(102020,1039929, 20493, 49944,98201, 8201111)
df_1<- data.frame(columna)
columna<-c(100388,9999, 33310, 49944)
df_2<- data.frame(columna)
columna<-c(248477,298374, 10000, 29999, 4000)
df_3<- data.frame(columna)
columna<-c(430010,950011, 53080, 110293, 974001, 292909, 1929911)
df_4<- data.frame(columna)

fruit <- c("apple","orange","banana","lemon")
df<- data.frame(fruit)
```

I tried this way:

```
for(i in 1:4){
  x<-nrow(as.formula(paste("df_", i, sep = "")))
  assign(paste("df_", i, sep = "")["fruit"],
         rep(df[i,], x)
  )
}
```

df_1 must have this output:

| columna | Fruit |
| --- | --- |
| 102020 | apple |
| 1039929 | apple |
| 20493 | apple |
| 49944 | apple |
| 98201 | apple |
| 8201111 | apple |

Any ideas?

Comment: You say you have 4 dataframes, yet you claim you want 4 dataframes. Your question is incoherent

Comment: `list2env(Map(transform, mget(ls(pattern = "^df_\\d+$")), fruit = fruit), .GlobalEnv)` Though if you are going to do the same operations to the different dataframes, you should have them in a list/ a grouped dataframe, etc

Comment: While I can sort of understand where you are going here, it would be better if you could provide some minimally reproducible versions of the four datasets. It would help people show you how it's done.

Comment: Yes, I would like to do the same operations. Do I need to create a list with the 4 dataframes?

Comment: I have added reproducible versions of the dataframes

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @onyambu - putting your data frames in a list will make it easier to apply the same operations across each.

Your Input:

```
columna<-c(102020,1039929, 20493, 49944,98201, 8201111)
df_1<- data.frame(columna)
columna<-c(100388,9999, 33310, 49944)
df_2<- data.frame(columna)
columna<-c(248477,298374, 10000, 29999, 4000)
df_3<- data.frame(columna)
columna<-c(430010,950011, 53080, 110293, 974001, 292909, 1929911)
df_4<- data.frame(columna)

fruit <- c("apple","orange","banana","lemon")
df<- data.frame(fruit)
```

Add data frames to a list then use for loop to adjust each.

```
# Combine DFs in a list
df_list <- list(df_1, df_2, df_3, df_4)

# iterate through each DF, adding the fruit from your fruit df for the respective index, i.
for (i in 1:length(df_list)){
  df_list[[i]][,"fruit"] <- df$fruit[i]
}
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
  columna fruit
1  102020 apple
2 1039929 apple
3   20493 apple
4   49944 apple
5   98201 apple
6 8201111 apple

[[2]]
  columna  fruit
1  100388 orange
2    9999 orange
3   33310 orange
4   49944 orange

[[3]]
  columna  fruit
1  248477 banana
2  298374 banana
3   10000 banana
4   29999 banana
5    4000 banana

[[4]]
  columna fruit
1  430010 lemon
2  950011 lemon
3   53080 lemon
4  110293 lemon
5  974001 lemon
6  292909 lemon
7 1929911 lemon
```